# How to install Windows10 and Windows7 in one drive (partition)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-10

I need to install windows10x64 and windows7x64 in one partition

I can install windowsXP like this but how about 7+10

I know about drive shrinking but I want single partion/drive not anything else

thanks

Comment: Are you referring to one partition each, or both in the same partition?  If you are talking about both in the same partition, the Windows installer won't do it, at least in the normal way.  You could approach it by running one in a VM.

Comment: But i can do with XP

Comment: Install Win10 in a VHD (native VHD boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too likely. You'd have stuff stepping over each other (there's two windows folders! two program files folders. Two of *everything*.)

Lets start at the bootloader. I've used visualbcd to look at what a typical bcd entry looks like

[image]

Maybe just maybe you could change systemroot and application path here to get *some* things to work. Then somehow convince one copy of windows to use a different registry hive automatically... and everything else.

So, at this point, lets turn back from the brink of madness, and use a handy feature that's been available since windows 7 - vhd boot. [Its officially supported](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn858566.aspx), and essentially you create and mount a VHD through disk management, install the OS using DISM with a command like `DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:D:\Sources\install.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:V:\` where d: is your cd rom drive, and v: is the VHD, add it to your bootloader, and it just works.

Need to access stuff in the VHD? You can mount it. Sick of windows 10? nuke the VHD, and remove it from the boot menu.